# Can I extract two words from a sentence using a regular expression?

Tags: qt, qregularexpression

I want to use a regular expression to extract two words from a sentence: Mobile and Application.

It should only be extracted when there are two words.

For example,

abcd Mobile defe Application is also true.

Mobile Application asdbfdvdsc is also true.

Application asdbdfbdfb Mobile is also true.

Mobile, Application
Regardless of the order/ no matter how many words there are between two words/ can I extract two words from a sentence using a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
(Mobile)(.*)(Application)|(Application)(.*)(Mobile)
```

Use the [QString.replace(const QRegularExpression &re, const QString &after)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-12) to extract the undesired words from the text:

```
#include <QRegularExpression>

QString text = 
"abcd Mobile defe Application is also true.\n
Mobile Application asdbfdvdsc is also true\n
Application asdbdfbdfb Mobile is also true.";

text.replace(QRegularExpression("(Mobile)(.*)(Application)|(Application)(.*)(Mobile)"), "\\2");
```